# Internal error when exporting image data from Google Earth Engine to Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, error, image, google-drive

I’m running a script on Google Earth Engine to download a couple years of data from an image collection for a region in the US, but the download keeps failing. The console gives the message “Tile error: An internal error has occurred.” The task manager gives the message "Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13)"

It’s frustrating because the script worked fine a few weeks ago, and the error message is very uninformative, so I’m not sure what’s wrong now. I have tried filtering by different dates, exporting for a smaller region, and changing the CRS, but nothing has worked. I've also submitted this issue to Google but I'm not sure if or when I'll hear back.

Here is my code:

```
// get irrigation data
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("UMT/Climate/IrrMapper_RF/v1_0");
var irrdata = dataset.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2019-12-31').select('classification');
var irrmap = irrdata.max();

// add to map
var visualization = {min: 0.0, max: 1.0, palette: ['blue']};
Map.addLayer(irrmap, visualization, 'IrrMapper');
Map.setCenter(-109.0247, 39.12509, 5);

// define area of interest
var ucrb = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-112.32864, 35.55848, -105.62641, 43.45218]);
Map.addLayer(ucrb)

// export data to Google drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: irrmap,
  description: 'IrrMapper_UCRB',
  region: ucrb,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12
});
```

Comment: This looks as a momentary bug. The link posted as an example doesn't work either: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples:Datasets/UMT/UMT_Climate_IrrMapper_RF_v1_0